# Store DataTable in view state

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

> I think I found it :D, wrong data :D – steve jobs

---

I have a datatable object I want to store it in Viewstate but some times an error occurred (not usual

```
Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Error serializing value 'Table1' of type 'System.Data.DataTable.'
```

Any help Please

Comment: if you are storing a large amount of rows and columns, ViewState might not be the best storage medium for you.

Comment: no, it not a big data I have only 5 rows, and I don't know why its working sometime and sometimes not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are facing is because of size of datatable.

Storing datatable in ViewState is not a good practice as it increases the size of your page and reduces the performance, also ViewState can be deciphered on the client side, so the DataTable is not secure.

You can do it through sessions or more better from Cache and if it is not being used frequently I suggest you to requery it from database.

Comment: the issue is I want to do some modification on the Datatable that is why I want to keen a temp version, and I use a view state ti ensure it's removed when I leave a page

Comment: What are the values present in the datatable, if you store an unserializable object in a table, then the table is no more 
serilizable. you will need to write a serializer/deserialzer for each of your controls.

Answer (score 0):

Use Session for storing DataTable because Viewstate is not efficient for storing large objects like DataTable as they wrapped with each server request.

```
  Session[dt] = datatableobj;
```

Comment: I have no large data, its only 5 rows, and its some time working normally